# Getting children component's state in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it "okay" (in the React.js sense) to get children component's value by using `ref`s and `state`? Or are there any "proper" ways to achieve this?

Why I think there might be another ways is that accessing children components by `ref`erencing and directly referencing their `state` seem quite suspicious.

My code looks as follows. This is a simplified one.

The thing is that `startDate` and `endDate` **must be updated only when** `_handleSubmit` is called because there're some logics that change the view when those two states are updated and that's a no-go situation here.

### some-parent-component.js

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';
import React from 'react';

import CustomDatepickerInput from './custom-datepicker-input';

class ParentWrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      endDate: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    };
    this._handleSubmit = this._handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    // Some logics that change the view when this.state.endDate or this.state.startDate is updated.

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <CustomDatepickerInput date={this.state.startDate} ref={c => this._startDate = c} />
            <CustomDatepickerInput date={this.state.endDate} ref={c => this._endDate = c} />
            <span className="diabetes-tabs-submit" onClick={this._handleSubmit}></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  _handleSubmit() {
    this.setState({
      startDate: moment(this._startDate.state.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      endDate: moment(this._endDate.state.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    })
  }
};

export default ParentWrapper;
```

### custom-datepicker-input.js

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';
import Pikaday from 'pikaday';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class CustomDatepickerInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      date: this.props.date,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    new Pikaday({
      field: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this),
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
      onSelect: this._handleDateChange,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input type="text" defaultValue={this.state.date} />
    );
  }

  _handleDateChange(date) {
    this.setState({date: moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')});
  }
};

export default CustomDatepickerInput;
```

Comment: Instead of using refs just pass a callback function down to children components from their parents... Invoke this whenever you want the parent to be informed of a change.

Comment: Yes...As @Maxwell suggested passing a callback function is a better approach. You might find reading react doc [refs-and-dom](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) helpful.